# Serving Files From Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a simple need, but there are so many azure options, I am not sure where to start.

I have a AppService (website) on azure from which I want to serve static PDFs for download.  In other words, there is a training page on the website, and on this page, I want to have url to the PDF to download it.

But I don't want the PDF's to be a part of the AppService files, I want them in storage so they are a separate from the website files.

How should this be done?

What I have found so far is: Azure Blob storage, but it's not clear to me how to use those with a URL.  The samples look like they are using code to download instead of a public URL.

I have also looked at Azure CDN, but that seems like more than I am looking for. Just need a simple location to store and download files.

Comment: Please don't add answers to your question. If you want to post your own version of the given answer, you can post as a separate answer, or (better yet) comment under the answer you were given. But your edit to your question, containing details of your answer, should be removed.

Comment: Is there a reason for suggesting that I not add the additional information?

Comment: The downside to creating a new answer is that it's too easy to miss if you just read the accepted answer, not knowing there is more info to be had. I also don't want to take points away from the accepted answer.  But I still don't see the benefit of adding a new answer, but I do see a downside to it.  The alternative, though, we be to add the edit to the accepted answer, but I am always hesitant to edit someone else's answer without a really good reason.

Comment: And you did not list any actual downsides to editing the question to add more info.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  I have moved my Edit to a separate answer. I didn't mean to rub you the wrong way on this, just wanted to fully understand the issue. I guess I didn't want to do this originally as I did not it to appear that I  was just stealing his answering and using it as my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can upload your PDFs to Azure Blob storage into a special container (e.g. download) and make that container and content public in either of two ways:

- public read access for blobs only: Blobs within the container can be read by anonymous request, but container data is not available. Anonymous clients cannot enumerate the blobs within the container.
- Full public read access: All container and blob data can be read by anonymous request. Clients can enumerate blobs within the container by anonymous request, but cannot enumerate containers within the storage account.

Then they are accessible by a URL like https://yourStor.blob.core.windows.net/download/train1.pdf

Answer (score 4):

You can make the blob container public so anyone with the link can download the file.
In this case you can just link to the file or return a 302 redirect from your app to the link, which also initiates the download.

Another option is to use SAS tokens.
These temporary tokens are generated using your storage account access key,
and are attached to the URL.
You can then give this final URL in the link to allow the user to download the file.
In this option the container can be kept private, and you control who can access what.
Now the token is only valid until it expires (you decide this time), so a user could give the link to another person and they could also download the document within that time.

The third option is to pipe the files through your app to the user.
Download the file from your back-end and then stream it to the user for download.
This option takes more resources on your back-end as threads and IO are used there for each download.
This option is the most secure as you can control who can download what.

Answer (score 2):

**To expand on the accepted answer**

Create a Storage Account, such as mystorage

In the storage account, create a container, such as mycontainer

On the container, set the Access Policy to Blob (Anonymous read access for blobs only).

Upload your file, such as myfile.txt to the container.

View the file Properties. It will show the URL to the file which is in this format: https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfile.txt

Note that the URL is case sensitive.